# Can't see images used in slideshow or other jQuery plug-ins in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am getting a weird error. I can see images in slideshow, lightbox, etc. in Firefox and Chrome but in Internet Explorer 8 there are no images. Something is wrong with JavaScript/jQuery I think.
I am using jQuery 1.4.2,

- jquery.flow.1.2.min.js
- jquery.bgpos.js
- jquery.easing.1.3.js
- jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js
- jquery.validate.js
- cufon-yui.js
- jquery.galleriffic.js
- DD_belatedPNG.js
- clearbox.js

Please check this. I have pasted images under slideshow, you can see those at
http://kaisweb.com/projects/resume/ and http://kaisweb.com/projects/resume/index.php?p=templates.

I tried to search but couldn't find anything. Even if I remove jQuery, still there are no images in Internet Explorer 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the its an issue related to the image format. Try opening the image in an editor such as photoshop and doing a save as and set the save as type to JPG.

Comment: Thanks alot, it fixed , i spent 2 days searching about this, thanks alot.

Comment: Wow I didnt know this could happen with png.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your server settings.  I pulled an image out of your source and tried to download it in IE: http://kaisweb.com/projects/resume/assets/images/resume/001.jpg.  This failed.  I then opened the same resource in FF with no issue.  I inspected the request/response in FireBug and didn't see anything strange.

I don't think the problem has anything to do with any of your scripts.

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem with .png formats for Internet Explorer. Background white when I want a transparent background in Internet Explorer.